# Java AES with random salt gives an error "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded"

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to run the following AES encryption with auto generated Salt. but it throws an error message when i try to decrypt. Mostly The idea is that,

I have a window which gets user name and password. then after that it will encrypt the data using that password. and when the user want to view it. he use the password to decrypt it.

**Code**

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Decrypts {
    private static final String password = "haasd";
    private static final String ALGO = "AES";

    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        byte[] encryptedValue = new Base64().encode(encVal);
        String ency = new String(encryptedValue);
        return ency;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new Base64().decodeBase64(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {

        try {
            String salt;
            int pswdIterations = 65536;
            int keySize = 256;
            salt = generateSalt();
            byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                    .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes,
                    pswdIterations, keySize);

            SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);

            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
            return key;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static String generateSalt() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
        random.nextBytes(bytes);
        String s = new String(bytes);
        return s;
    }

}
```

**Updated Code**

```
public class Decrypts {
    private static final String password = "haasd";
    private static final String ALGO = "AES";

    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        String SALT = generateSalt();
        byte[] saltBytes = SALT.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Saltbytes ; " + saltBytes);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes,
                65536, 256);

        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        byte[] encryptedValue = new Base64().encode(encVal);
        String ency = new String(encryptedValue);
        return ency;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        String SALT = generateSalt();
        byte[] saltBytes = SALT.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Saltbytes ; " + saltBytes);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes,
                65536, 256);

        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] decordedValue = new Base64().decodeBase64(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    public static String generateSalt() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(password.getBytes());
        byte bytes[] = new byte[120];
        random.nextBytes(bytes);
        String s = new String(bytes);
        System.out.println("Salt ; " + s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating **random salt** in both of `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`, salt generation will give different one in both methods, as a result, you will get the error `Given final block not properly padded`.

In fact you should use only one common salt that you specified (fixed salt) or random generated. Let's define a class variable for it.

```
private static final String password = "haasd";
private static final String ALGO = "AES";
private static final String SALT = generateSalt(); //generate salt once
```

Then in your `generateKey()`, dont generate salt again, just use class member `SALT`

```
//byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] saltBytes = SALT.getBytes("UTF-8"); //using class member SALT
```

#### Alternative way

is to accept user entered password as argument in encryption and decryption methods. Then use that password to generate salt, like this

```
public static String generateSalt(String password) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(password.getBytes());
    ...
}
```

Comment: if i do that, won't same word if i encrypt will give the same encrypted value? because the password and the salt both are the same for everything? because i don't decrypt it at the same time. it will store the encrypted value and when user wanted only it will decrypt. then i need to specify the salt right?

Comment: @checkmate Yes basically, in your case, salt generated must be same for a pair of work encrypt() and decrypt(). If a word is encrypted with a salt `A`, that encrypted text need to decrypted with same salt `A`. So you need to maintain generated salt(s)(in encryption time) for future usages (for decryption time). Whether saving in file system or any repository way.

Comment: Hmmmmm well is there any other method i can use a random salt and do the encryption and decryption?

Comment: If so accept user entered password as arg in encrypt and decrypt, and use fixed salt. Then use that password in `new PBEKeySpec()`.

Comment: Hy, I am really thankful for your time. nevertheless, i am still getting the same encrypted key if the password is same. I checked salt are not different to one to another. and key is always the same.

Comment: @checkmate If you want different salt if the password is same in different credential. I think you should use also username together in salt generation. :)